# Command line latex with additional commands: `latex '\newif...`

Tags: macros

Long time ago I did set up my CV compile system with some `\ifLANG` and then compiled the files with

```
pdflatex '\newif\ifLANG\LANGtrue\input{main}'
```

after which the `main.tex` starts with

```
\ifcsname ifLANG\endcsname\else\newif\ifLANG\LANGfalse\fi
\documentclass{...}
...
```

The idea was that compiling the file without any tricks provided the default language (English in my case), but with simple invocations (via Makefile) I could switch the language to some other (in my case Japanese and Italian).

Unfortunately it seems that something has changed in the guts and nowadays this doesn't work anymore, I get an error

```
$ latex '\newif\ifjapanese \input test-if'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(./test-if.tex)
! Incomplete \ifcsname; all text was ignored after line 1.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> \newif\ifjapanese \input test-if

?
```

Anyone can see a reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: The latest documentation of upLaTeX, uplatex.dtx, is an example of building both Japanese and English documents from the common source. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `\ifLANG` is defined in the command line, you have

```
\ifcsname ifLANG\endcsname\else\newif\ifLANG\LANGfalse\fi
```

and the test is true, so TeX wants to skip over the “else” part, but keeping track of the nested conditionals. And, in this case, `\ifLANG` is a conditional, so the `\fi` matches it and there is none to match `\ifcsname`.

Solution:

```
\ifcsname ifLANG\endcsname
\else
  \expandafter\newif\csname ifLANG\endcsname
  %\LANGfalse % not needed
\fi
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly indeed. But for my recollection - was there some change that did this? I faintly remember that I copied the code from a previous version of my CV and it *did* work back then. But I might be wrong and no way to check, though.

Comment: @norbert Probably you were not doing `\newif` from the command line.

Comment: Probably yes, but I had some system like this, so I am suprised. Anyway, thanks for your solution!